# including javascript files in my page

Tags: javascript

I have many (almost 15) javascript files which I am using in my webpage.
What is the best way to include all of these files?

Simply at bottom or is there some other technique that should be used which can load javascript faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using a **parallel/non-blocking** javascript loader.

Following are some great libraries that could do this for you..

http://headjs.com/

http://requirejs.org/

http://labjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could combine and minify them. [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) could do that.

Comment: @DavidHedlund, not necessarily (as far as combining them). You wouldn't want to combine common library files, such as jQuery, which would perform much better if referenced from a common CDN. Additionally it's possible that some modules are only appropriate on some pages, in which case they should be served as separate files.

Answer (score 1):

Google Closure Compiler has a convient web api for merging and minifying all your js.
https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref

You can put a script tag with a direct link to the api.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't quite mastered implementing all this yet I have found that a fair amount of minification & concatenation can be automated by servers, I have learned a fair amount from reading the (well-commented) .htaccess file in the HTML5 Boilerplate and associated docs.

Modernizr also features an asyncronous loader function and it was well enough documented that I was able to get it to work when I just couldn't quite figure out require.js

Answer (score 0):

You could use a script loader library or you can do it yourself.

## Where to include scripts and how the browser loads resources

Always at the bottom just before the closing `<body>` tag, to enhance the user experience. It ensures that the page content gets rendered first, which gives the impression that your pages load quicker.

The browser runs a single thread and will process the page content from top to bottom, if it happens on a resource, it first has to retrieve the resource, process it and then only continue with the next tag on the page. Since we generally want to wait for the DOM to be finished loading, before running any scripts in any case, this strategy is always a win win.

## Size matters

For production you want to ensure that all your scripts are minified regardless of the strategy you are going to employ to get them loaded (smaller size == less to download == quicker)

## The correct order

Most important is always the dependency order, if we call a function or access a variable and the browser doesn't know about it first, the script will fail. You want to ensure that a script is only included after any scripts they depend on. So the first thing to do is to work out the order by which you need to include and introduce functionality to the browser.

## How to include scripts into a page

There is only one way to include a script in a page (not recommending same origin ajax/eval) and that is by means of the `<script>` tag.

There are only 2 ways to create a `<script>` tag:

1. Statically located in html or
2. dynamically added with JavaScript.

### Statically added scripts

Since we know the order we need our scripts included we can add them one by one after each other like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.5.2/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.5.2/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js"></script>
```

### Dynamically added scripts

There are three ways to effectively create script tags in the dom, dynamically, which we will explore. These are certainly not the only ways...

#### document.write

The write method will append to the existing dom.

```
document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>');
```

But now we have a problem as there is no way of telling that the script is done loading, because we have to wait until it is complete before loading the next one or calling something that is defined there.

#### document.createElement

The createElement method creates a dom element and we can insert it anywhere in the dom we choose. 
The following example checks if jQuery exists or creates a `<script>` element to go fetch it. In any event, the function ready_go is called and we should have jQuery.

```
(function() {
    if (!window.jQuery) {
        var jq = document.createElement('script');
        jq.type = 'text/javascript';
        jq.async = true;
        jq.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(jq, s);

        jq.onreadystatechange = jq.onload = ready_go;
    } else ready_go();
})();
```

#### jQuery.getScript

Since we have jQuery now we don't have to do things the hard way, getScript takes as first argument the script url and will call the function as 2nd argument once the script is complete.

```
function ready_go() {
    $.getScript('http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.5.2/jquery.tablesorter.min.js', function () {
         // script is done loading we can include the next
         $.getScript('http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.5.2/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js', function () {
             // script is done loading we can include the next or start using our stuff
         });
    });
}
```

## Where to get the scripts from?

You either want to get the scripts from public CDN or host them yourself. An important concept to bear in mind is that scripts, as with any other resources get cached by the browser and you will not be required to repeatedly download the same scripts.

### Scripts from a Content Delivery Network

The advantage of a CDN is twofold;

1. you get closer to the user, because a CDN consists of POPs distributed across the world and even though you are calling one url the server responding may be different
2. many sites may use the same CDN if your user already got jQuery from google's CDN when visiting my site his browser will simply use the cache copy already in its possession when requested by you.

### Scripts served from origin (your server)

I agree with the strategy that @Mario and @Xharze suggests, beats including 18 scripts on every page.

Use CDNs where scripts are available but for the rest.

Concatenate all your scripts together, keeping in mind that the same dependency order applies, and minify them.

Having one script will simplify your includes and because the browser will cache the script no additional downloads will be required again, especially beneficial in application used for extended periods and accessing many pages.

The only advantage separate scripts hold is for users who exit from the landing page and why do we care to optimise for them they're not going to stay because of it.

nJoy!